# Larger border-bottom breaks border-left and border-right in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome, border

When overriding the size of the `border-bottom` in a `div` that already has a 1px border, Firefox and Chrome render the `border-left` and `border-right` incorrectly:

#### HTML

```
<div></div>
```

#### CSS

```
div{
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #9fd;
    border-bottom: 50px solid #333;
}
```

**jsFiddle link:** http://jsfiddle.net/azSrQ/

#### Expected result (Safari 6.0.1)

[image: Safari 6.0.1]

#### Actual result (Firefox 15.0.1 and Chrome 22)

[image: Firefox and Chrome]

The left and right border always stop halfway down the `border-bottom` in the latest Chrome and Firefox. I couldn't find any reports of this in Bugzilla or Chromium's issues page.

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

That's weird i guess. Or maybe it's the default behaviour? They stop exactly at 50% of the bottom border.

Anyway, here's a method to emulate it:

```
div:after {
    content:".";
    color:#333;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-50px; left:-1px; right:-1px;
    line-height:25px;
    border-left:1px solid #9fd; border-right:1px solid #9fd;
}​
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/GWSFR/)**

Tested and working on latest Chrome and Safari, little issue with FF (win)

Answer (score 1):

Per spec, this should give a sloped gradient from one border width to the other.  But when one of the widths is only 1px, that generates to the thing you see above....

Comment: That's interesting. Which spec are you referring to?

Comment: Hmm.  Used to be in http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-background/ but looks like they've loosened up the language to be basically "whatever you want to do"...